# C# .Net 7 MVC Background Service EmailSendingService Cannot consume scoped service Project.Core.DB' from singleton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, background-service, .net-7.0

I would like to create a background service to send emails in my .Net 7 MVC project and create a simple background service that doesn't do anything yet. I have followed various solutions online by adding a scoped service however those don't seem to work in my case. my entire project is using a repository pattern and the error i am getting is as follows when trying to run the project.

```
System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: TestProject.Workers.EmailSendingService': Cannot consume scoped service 'Project.Core.DB' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)'
```

I dont know where to continue looking to add a scope service.

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Connection String configurations
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ClientDatabase"));
});

// background services
builder.Services.AddHostedService<EmailSendingService>();
```

Background Service

```
public class EmailSendingService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _service;
    private readonly ILogService _log;
    

    public EmailSendingService(ILogService log, IServiceProvider service)
    {
        _service = service;
        _log = log;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var scope = _service.CreateScope();
        var scopedService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DB>();

        // do work here.
    }
}
```

LogService.cs

```
public class LogService : ILogService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IUtilityService _util;

    public LogService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUtilityService util)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _util = util;
    }

    public async Task LogMessageToFileAsync(string message)
    {
        var path = $"{_util.GetHostDirectory()}\\DevLogs";

        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        if (!File.Exists($"{path}\\Info.txt"))
            File.Create($"{path}\\Info.txt");

        await using StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(path, "Info.txt"));
        await outputFile.WriteLineAsync("This is a sentence.");
    }
}
```

LogRepository.cs

```
public class LogRepository : Repositories<Log>, ILogRepository
{
  private readonly DB _db;

  public LogRepository(DB context) : base(context)
  {
      _db = context;
  }
}
```

DBContext.cs

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // automatically excludes the following userid from all user queries
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(a => a.Id != 1);

        #if DEBUG
            modelBuilder.Seed();
        #endif
    }
}
```

The only background service here is the **EmailSendingService ** LogService is my businessLogic.

When i remove the ILogService DI, then the application runs no problem, but all of my businesslogic is contained within my 'Service classes' and the DI for DB Context doesnt seem to work.

Where am i going wrong, or where could i inject my DB context to my businesslogic classes.

Comment: What account are you using when you start the service?  The code needs an user account.  You may need to setup a relay for the email : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above?force_isolation=true

Comment: No account is needed, it is a background worker service inside of an mvc project.

Comment: Is it a real windows service?  Services are run in OS and have an optional Run As parameter.  Email needs a user account and running a service with default settings will not have a user account.  That is why it works when not running as a service because there is an account.

Comment: It is not a real windows service it is a MVC WORKER SERVICE. no account is needed. it has nothing to do with the settings is has to do with DI and Scoped Services. i have run many worker services and have never needed to change user accounts.......this is the first service that is using a completely different pattern.

Comment: The service is run by default as LocalSystem which doesn't have an environment.  So there is no account.  You need to configure the service.  See : https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2022/03/22/windowsservice-2/?force_isolation=true

Comment: as mentioned the account is not the issue, maybe drop that now?

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to get this to work, without needing to setup silly user accounts and environments since it has nothing to do with that, please ignore @jdweng, i think he was misunderstanding the question.

This is a bit of a hacky approach but fits my needs.

I overloaded my DBContext as follows

```
public class DB : DbContext
{
    public DB(string connectionString)
        : base(GetOptions(connectionString))
    {
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions(string connectionString)
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString)
            .Options;
    }

    public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("dbo");
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // automatically excludes the following userid from all user queries
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(a => a.Id != 1);
    }
}
```

i then create a utility function which will read the client connection string from appsettings.json

```
public string GetClientConnectionString()
{
        var appSettingValue = _config.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:ClientDatabase").Value;

        if (appSettingValue != null)
            return appSettingValue;

        return string.Empty;
}
```

My email sending service now looks like this until i find a solution to the DI issue i am having.

```
public class EmailSendingService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IUtilityService _util;
    private readonly ILogService _log;

    public EmailSendingService(IUtilityService util)
    {
        _util = util;
        _log = new LogService(new UnitOfWork(new DB(_util.GetClientConnectionString())), util);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _log.AddLog("this is my message");
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```